# Flutter: read large number of nodes in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I try to read data from Firebase and it doesn't work with a large number of nodes,

**Here is what I tried :**

```
  Future<int> test() async {
     final response = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('...').once();
     var urls=[];
     response.value.forEach((v) => urls.add(v));
     print(urls);
     return urls.length;
  }
```

**Result :**

It works well with some test data. Example:

[image]

[image]

but if I try to read 90 nodes, example :

[image]

**Result :**

> (dynamic) => void' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, dynamic) =>
>   void' of 'f

[image]

Any idea?

---

**NEW**

**I found that if the key is for example :**

> -LU645_UgPbGZhBsneOq

(auto generated by a cloud function using .push().set() )

then it doesn't work.

> **More details : if the key is not numeric, then it doesn't work**

[image]

Why?

Comment: home.dart , line 233, what is that?

Comment: line 233 : response.value.forEach((v) => urls.add(v));

Comment: if I change the child from "product/1/1/images" (data inside are populated by a cloud fnt) with "product/1/1/test", then it works, strange....

Comment: I found that if the key is -LU645_UgPbGZhBsneOq  then it doesn't work.... why??? any idea?

Comment: what data inside  ->   -LU645_UgPbGZhBsneOq  ?   paste a screenshot

Comment: I edited the question with a screenshot, both test2 and test3 have been created manually, just the name of the key change, I've really no luck:(

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886373/flutter-wait-until-firebase-data-are-retrieved-and-a-string-modified-before-wri?noredirect=1#comment94619363_53886373  ? I'm really stuck.. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use the node names given by push, then the value returned by once().value is a Map. Thus to iterate over it with foreach needs a function taking two arguments instead of one (which is exactly what the errormessage is telling you):

response.value.forEach((dynamic key, dynamic v) => urls.add(v))

this should give you in urls a list of maps with a "name" and an "url" key. The parameter "key" in the foreach function would be the nodename containing the name and url.

Why does a single-valued foreach function work with numerical node names? If you assign numerical node names firebase will return those nodes as an array. As your sample trees lack the "0"-Node you get "null" as the first element of the array.